# import copy isn't working on sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext

I'm learning about copy functions and when I tried to run the code below, I get an error on lines 1 and 4, specifically "'module' object is not callable."
I tried it on repl.it, and it worked fine, is there an extra step I'm missing?

I can't seem to find anything on the internet, but I'm probably just not looking up the right things.

```py
import copy

spam = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
cheese = copy.copy(spam)
cheese[1] = 42
print(spam)
print(cheese)
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `cheese = copy(spam)`? That would cause this error.

Comment: no, I pasted what I had directly on here.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you run the script, or is it just in the editor? Sometimes IDEs have problems in their parsing.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the difference is, I'm still pretty new to this. I get the error after clicking "build" which I'm assuming is the same as running it

Comment: Your code looks fine, so this seems like a SublimeText bug. Maybe it has an issue when a module contains a function with the same name.

Comment: Makes sense, is there anything I could try to do to fix it or no?

Comment: Run the script from a terminal window, not from the editor.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how do I do that? Do you mean on sublime or with the actual python terminal?

Comment: I mean open a command prompt window and type `python /path/to/your/script.py`

Comment: I tried that, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Sublime includes a Python interpreter, but it's for internal plugin use and not for running external code. For running Python scripts, it just executes `python`; I would verify that running `python` on your system gives you a version of Python that supports this (for example if it's a Python 3 thing, `python` may be executing Python 2 and thus it doesn't work().

Comment: I figured it out, it's because I named it copy.py and I changed it to copyExample.py, and that fixed it. Not sure why it's like that, but if someone could explain it, that'd be great. I only changed it after noticing that all my other files were named like that

Comment: @ShamsSikder It is a quite funny bug. If you import a module, python searches for a module with the same name and local files have precedence over other modules in sys.path, see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path.
Hence your copy.py module imports itself (instead of the expected copy module from the python lib) and stores the import in the global variable copy. This leads to a recursive variable and you access your own module with copy, and with copy.copy, and even copy.copy.copy.copy.